# Unused variables in fragment shaders change the render result

Tags: opengl, glsl

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core 
uniform vec4 Ambient;
uniform vec3 LightColor;
uniform vec3 LightDirection;
uniform vec3 HalfVector;
uniform float Shininess;
uniform float Strength;
in vec4 color;
in vec3 Normal;

out vec4 FragColor;
out vec3 directfeed;
out vec3 normalfeed;

void main()
{
    float diffuse = max(0.0f, dot(Normal, LightDirection));
    normalfeed = Normal;
    directfeed = LightDirection;
    float specular = max(0.0f, dot(Normal, HalfVector));
    if(diffuse <= 0.00001)
        specular = 0.0f;
    else
        specular = pow(specular, Shininess);
    vec4 ReflectLight = vec4(LightColor*specular*Strength, 0.0);
    FragColor = min(color*Ambient+ReflectLight, vec4(1.0));
}
```

if I delete these two lines `normalfeed = Normal;`and `directfeed = LightDirection;`, result will be different, but these two parameters `normalfeed` and `directfeed`  don't work at all, why? And if I try to output the two variables to feedback buffer, I do it like this:

```
char* oVerts[] = { "normalfeed" ,"gl_NextBuffer","directfeed" };
glTransformFeedbackVaryings(Program, 3, oVerts, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
```

after link `Program` again,nothing come out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use transform feedback in the fragment shader. Only vertex oder geometry shaders are allowed. For documentation on this, please see:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTransformFeedbackVaryings.xhtml

What do you expect from the variables `normalfeed` and `directfeed`? Do you want them to generate some output in a framebuffer? Than you have to enable output on more than one color attachment. For setting this up, I would recommend to read the documention of the following functions:

```
glDrawBuffers
glBindFramebuffer
glBindRenderbuffer
glRenderbufferStorage
glFramebufferRenderbuffer
```

If the variables you have declared are for debugging purpose, it could be interesting to render them into a texture:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

In a second pass, these debug texture(s) may then be used to draw a quad overlaying the real scene. This technique is often used to visualize and debug the depth buffer or surface normals.